# Bind a Object in subscribe Angular 5

Tags: angular

all I'm trying to getting data from the WebApi and Getting Undfind when I'm going to bind data to global variables.

Here is My subscribe

```
    export class OverallSummaryGaugeComponent implements OnInit {

  gaugeVal: any;
  bfd;
  pb: ProductionBreakDown[];
  gaugeSummaryType: String;
  constructor(private _sampleDataService: SampleDataObjectService, private _dashboard: DashboardService) { }
  customizeText(arg) {
    return arg.valueText + ' %';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gaugeVal = this._sampleDataService.CompletedPrasantage;
    this.getallData();
  }
  getallData() {
    this._dashboard.getProductionBreakDownByDate()
    .subscribe(pb => this.pb = pb
    );
    console.log(this.pb);
  }
}
```

when the I change the Code like this Its Print data.

```
this._dashboard.getProductionBreakDownByDate()
          .subscribe(pb => console.log(pb)
          );
          console.log(this.bd);
      }
```

but I'm trying to bind it the same type of list that getting Undefined.

Here is my Observable code

```
    @Injectable()
export class DashboardService extends BaseService {
    private _getProductionBreakDown = UrlsConfig.ptsapi + 'productionBreakDown/filterByDate/2018-12-17';
    constructor(private _dataAccessService: DataAccessService) {
        super(_dataAccessService);
    }
    // getting ProductionBreakDown Data
    getProductionBreakDownByDate(): Observable<ProductionBreakDown[]> {
        return this._dataAccessService.get<ProductionBreakDown[]>(this._getProductionBreakDown);
    }

}
```

Here is the model class

```
export class ProductionBreakDown {
    TotalTargetQty: number;
    TotalCompletedQty: number;
    BreakdownTypeId: number;
    ProductionScheduleId: number;
    BreakdownType: number;
    ProductionSchedule: any;
    TargetBagQty: number;
    TargetPOQty: number;
    CompletedPOQty: number;
    CompletedBagQty: number;
    CompletedBoxQty: number;
    ProductionDate: any;
    HourlyProductionBreakdowns: any;
    IsDeleted: any;
    Id: number;
    OwnerId: any;
}
```

Comment: can please add full method here, current code shows some syntax error

Comment: Ok Wait I will add

Comment: Code is added. Have you soloution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Http to retrieve data is an async operation. So it goes like this:

1) The ngOnInit calls the service, which sends a get request to the server.

2) The service code returns an observable.

3) Any code after the subscribe in the component is executed.

This step means that your `console.log` below is executed *before* the data is returned in step #5

```
  getallData() {
    this._dashboard.getProductionBreakDownByDate()
    .subscribe(pb => this.pb = pb   // <-- Not executed until step #6
    );
    console.log(this.pb);  // <-- executed as part of step #3, so undefined
  }
```

4) The UI displays. NOTE: At this point, your `pb` variable is NOT yet set.

5) At some later point in time, the server returns a response.

6) The code within the first function passed to the subscribe method is executed. It is at this point that your `pb` variable is set.

7) Angular's change detection picks up that the `pb` variable is now set and rebinds the UI.

Because of step #4, you need to add code in your UI (in your HTML) that handles `undefined` up until step #7 when it rebinds.

This is usually done one of two ways:

**Option 1:**

Add an `*ngIf='pb'` somewhere in a top element. This will prevent the UI from attempting to display until the `pb` property is set.

**OR**

**Option 2:**

Use the safe navigation operator on any element the references a property of the `pb` property.

For example, to bind to the TargetBagQty property:

```
{{ pb?.TargetBagQty }}
```

This ensures that the binding only navigates to the TargetBagQty property of `pb` if `pb` has a value.

Also, you need to include *all* code you want to execute *after* data is retrieved within the subscribe ... so like this:

```
  getallData() {
    this._dashboard.getProductionBreakDownByDate()
    .subscribe(pb => {
        this.pb = pb;
        console.log(this.pb);    //<-- both lines are now within the subscribe function
    });
```

}

Comment: You are the person who teaches me how to code angular from pluralsight. thank you. I had watched you all angular videos in the pluralsight.

Comment: Cool! I cover this in detail here: https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=angular-2-getting-started-update&author=deborah-kurata&name=angular-2-getting-started-update-m9&clip=4&mode=live at time code: 3:44